# How to set mouse position without importing user32.dll in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set mouse position at `origin(0,0)`, we have tried using user32.dll and `SetCursorPos()` function its working fine. But we are getting some security error while importing user32.dll in our running application.

We are searching any other method to set mouse position.
If any knows about this please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a WPF project or WinForm project ?

Comment: _"some security error"_ - is not particularly helpful.  Is your WPF app a _ClickOnce_ app by chance?

Comment: I am try to upload this on Bloomberg App Portal. So we fetching this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try that:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
```

You have to add the assemblies "System.Windows.Forms" and "System.Drawing".